# Why does Σ1/x diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Why does the following series diverge?

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$$

I've tried to make sense of it, but can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be an index at some point?

Comment: Are you asking for an intuitive explanation?

Comment: you should be more specific than $\sum 1/x$, do you mean $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's from 1 to infinity.

Comment: @Mud you probably mean $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 1/i$? ;-)

Comment: ha. yeah I do. thanks

Comment: @JohnSmith I asked this similar question not too long ago, check my profile. I had a lot of great answers!